# What would this set look like

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, geometry, analysis, matrices

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be the set of $\left(x,y,z\right)$,
$x\ge y\ge z$ , which are the three eigenvalues of $diag\left(1,2,3\right)+Udiag\left(-1,-2,-4\right)U^{T}$,
where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix. Is there any point of $$T=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:x\ge y\ge z,0\le x\le2,-1\le y\le1,-3\le z\le-1,x+y+z=-1\right\} ,$$ not in $S$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any helpful answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it's just the point $(1,0,0)$. Remember that the diagonal entries of a diagonal matrix are it's eigenvalues and that the matrix $Udiag(−1,−2,−4)U^T$ has the same eigenvalues for any $U$ by similarity.

Comment: @mtiano: Well, at least (2,0,-3) is in $S$, and there should be many more points in S. Do you know what this set looks like? Thanks!

Comment: @user1551: You are right that $(2,2,2)$ does not lie in $x+y+z=-1$, but is $(2,−1.5,−1.5)$ in $S$? Thanks!

Comment: @user1551: Thanks, but what exactly does $S$ look like in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
or what points of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are in $S$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: According to Weyl's inequalities, $S$ is contained in $$T=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:x\ge y\ge z,0\le x\le2,-1\le y\le1,-3\le z\le-1,x+y+z=-1\right\} ,$$ but what points of $T$ are not in $S$ if there is any? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just curious: a different but related [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421683/existence-of-a-common-minimizer/421765#421765) was asked before. Where does the expression of the form $D+USU^T$ come from?